# Treating "integer" data as "string" in the "entity_id" field of customer

Tags: querystring

I'm facing an intriguing issue in Magento 2, and I would like to know if anyone has come across this or has any relevant information about it. In the Magento 2 database schema, the "entity_id" field of the "customer" table is defined as an "integer" type. However, whenever Magento processes this field, it treats it as a string.

For example, when extracting the following query in the Magento database:

**DELETE** **FROM** customer_grid_flat
**WHERE** (entity_id **IN**('8940274'))

We can observe that the value '8940274' is being passed as a string, even though the database schema defines this field as an "integer" type.

This inconsistency has intrigued me and made me question why Magento 2 converts "integer" values to "string" when handling the "entity_id" field. Is there any specific reason for this behavior? Could it be an intentional feature of Magento 2, or perhaps a potential bug?

I appreciate any information or insights you can share regarding this matter. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try these all steps it can be useful to you

1.**Database Schema:**
In the Magento 2 database schema, the **customer** table's **entity_id** field is defined as an integer. This definition follows the standard database practice of using an integer data type for primary key fields.

2.**EAV System in Magento 2:**
Magento 2 utilizes an Entity Attribute Value (EAV) system for flexible and extensible data modeling. The EAV system allows dynamic addition of attributes without modifying the database schema for every new attribute.

3.**Entity ID Management:**
In the EAV system, each entity in Magento, such as a customer or a product, is assigned a unique identifier known as the "entity_id." This identifier serves as a key to associate various attributes with the entity.

4.**Entity ID as a String:**
Magento 2 treats the **entity_id** as a string throughout its processing to accommodate the flexibility provided by the EAV system. This means that even though the **entity_id** field is defined as an integer in the database schema, Magento processes it as a string to ensure compatibility with the EAV structure

5.**Query Execution:**
When executing a query, such as the example you provided **(DELETE FROM customer_grid_flat WHERE (entity_id IN('8940274')))**, Magento treats the value **'8940274'** as a string because it is consistent with the EAV system's handling of the **entity_id** field.

To summarize, the observed behavior of Magento 2 treating the **entity_id** field of the **customer** table as a string is intentional and aligned with the EAV system's design. Although the database schema defines the field as an integer, Magento uses a string representation for consistency and compatibility with the flexible attribute management provided by the EAV system.

```
      *HOPE YOU IT CAN BE USEFULL FOR YOU*
```